# need help to identify issue

Tags: node.js, nestjs, fastify

Following is my snippet of main.ts

```
  try {
    process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
      console.error(err); <------- no console
    });
    const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
      AppModule,
      new FastifyAdapter(),
    );
    app.enableCors();
    app.useGlobalFilters(new AllExceptionsFilter());

    await app.listen(3000, () => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
      console.log('listen callback'); <------- no console
    }).then(() => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
      console.log('started'); <------- no console
    });
  } catch (error) {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-console
    console.log('catch', error); <----- only this gets consoled as undefined
  }
```

My app gets connected to database (verified), just that it doesn't start.

Comment: in `app.listen(3000, () => {` if you pass a callback, no promises will be returned, so remove the callback

Answer (score 1):

Calling `.listen()` with a callback argument means this method is going to return `undefined`. You are trying to call `.then()` on that `undefined` value.

You need simply need to change your listen call to this:

```
await app.listen(3000, () => 'Server running on port 3000...');
```

BONUS: You can test this yourself by setting that call to `listen` to a variable and then console log it:

```
const result = await app.listen(3000, () => 'Server running on port 3000...');

console.log(result);
//undefined
```

Comment: Thanks for revert, I understand what you are saying, I've tried above but still, the server doesn't start. Instead, I'm getting unHandledRejection error, that's the reason I've wrapped around try-catch.

Comment: Do you have this code in Github or somewhere where we can take a look?